# Cordova InAppBrowser open url externally using mobile default browser

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, phonegap-plugins, inappbrowser

I created a Cordova apps which my webpage is launch using Cordova InAppBrowser. In my webpage, I have some url link which I would like to open externally using default mobile browser after click. I have tried window.open in my webpage javascript but it is still not working for Android device. Is there any alternative way to do this?

`cordova.InAppBrowser.open(myurl, '_self', 'location=no,toolbar=no');`